# ServletContextListener - Attribute - Setting java.sql.Connection object

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, nullpointerexception, database-connection, servlet-listeners

Although I've already found this issue solution, I'm wondering why it works this way.

I've created a class that implements ServletContextListener and I set as a Context Attribute an object intended to built a java.sql.Connection (MySQL DBMS) available for all application.

As the Java Tutorial says, after JDBC 4.0 release, it isn't necessary to call Class.forName("...") anymore to initialize a particular Driver.

For JavaSE projects it's true, but for Web applications it isn't though.

When I call createStatement() for instance, the Container throws an NullPointerException as  the java.sql.Connection doesn't exist. Thus, I added Class.forName("...") on top of the Connection "setter" and it works flawlessly.

Note: I use Netbeans. The particular project which holds this example has set as one of its libraries the latest mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> *I've created a class that implements ServletContextListener and I set as a Context Attribute an object intended to built a java.sql.Connection (MySQL DBMS) available for all application.*

Bad idea. Your web application has now not only a threadunsafe interaction with the DB, but your web application will also crash after running for ~8 hours when MySQL decides to reclaim the connection because it's been opened for too long. Don't do that. Use a connection pool and just write JDBC code according the standard JDBC idiom, i.e. open *and* close all resources in shortest possible scope.

---

> *As the Java Tutorial says, after JDBC 4.0 release, it isn't necessary to call Class.forName("...") anymore to initialize a particular Driver.*
>
> *For JavaSE projects it's true, but for Web applications it isn't though.*

It's true for web applications as well if the JDBC 4.0 compliant driver JAR file containing the `/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file is been placed in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the webapp, not elsewhere.

---

> *When I call createStatement() for instance, the Container throws an NullPointerException as the java.sql.Connection doesn't exist. Thus, I added Class.forName("...") on top of the Connection "setter" and it works flawlessly.*

The container can impossibly throw this particular exception. It's more likely that it's just your own code which did it. By the way, the fact that this exception is been thrown instead of a `SQLException: no suitable driver` also indicates that you suppressed any caught `SQLException` during `DriverManager#getConnection()` and continued the code flow instead of throwing that exception and/or aborting the code flow in some way. This is in turn also a bad idea. Don't suppress exceptions if you absolutely can't continue the code flow.

Comment: Thank you for a complete answer. Regarding what you said "Bad idea", it wasn't my intention to use it as an official application, but to test the ServletContext attribute as an "JDBC" server, that's all. You're right. The exception wouldn't be thrown by the Container it self, but the NullPointerException was thrown for sure due the object I tried to "rescue" within one of the Servlet and I tested the resultant object it self with "instanceof" and the answer was "null"...

Comment: I've tried your suggestion about insert the MySQL Connector/J JAR file into my application WEB-INF/lib but unfortunately the NullPointerException was thrown again. By the way, I forgot to mention that my app Container is the Apache Tomcat. Note: I've checked the JAR content and the folder META-INF/service with the respect "java.sql.Driver" was there too.

Comment: Apparently it's a Tomcat specific issue. What Tomcat version are you using? Perhaps it's an old one which doesn't (correctly) take `/META-INF/services` in JARs into account at all during class loading.

Comment: Tomcat Version: 6.0.35. I took a look at other websites in order to find what is missing. One of them says that, beyond trivial (WEB-INF/lib) it's necessary to configure something within DD and other application XML. I don't know whether is necessary to do all that or not.